# Count percentage inside a progress bar

Tags: php, wordpress, math, count, percentage

Need a bit of help with a math related question.

My code is as follows, where it displays all hourly rates from all users (e.g.: 35, 30, 45, 68, etc)

```
$args = array(
    'role' => 'freelance_author',   
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {                 
        $all_hourly_rate    = get_the_author_meta( 'hourly_rate', $user->ID );                  
        echo '<p>' . $all_hourly_rate . '</p>';                 
    }               
}
```

Now I'd like to have an extra variable, where it grabs the highest number (e.g. 68).

Then the next step is implement this inside a progress bar

```
<div class="uk-progress">
    <div class="uk-progress-bar" style="width:<?php echo esc_attr( $author_hourly_rate ); ?>%;"></div>
</div>
```

Let's say a specific author has an hourly rate of $34, which is 50% of the highest hourly rate (68) (100% on the progress bar), then the `$author_hourly_rate` should be `50`% for that specific author.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: (34 * 100) / 68 = 50%. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: How to grab the highest number from this variable `$all_hourly_rate` in the `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each `user` in the `result` and check if their `hourly_rate` is greater than the `max_hourly_rate`

```
$args = array(
    'role' => 'freelance_author',   
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {

    // set default $max_hourly_rate as the first result UID
    $max_hourly_rate = get_the_author_meta( 'hourly_rate', $user_query->results[0]->ID);

    for ( $i=1; $i<count($user_query->results); $i++ ) {              
        $user = $user_query->results[$i];

        $hourly_rate    = get_the_author_meta( 'hourly_rate', $user->ID );                  
        echo '<p>' . $hourly_rate . '</p>';                 

        //set max_hourly_rate if the users hourly_rate is greater
        if ($hourly_rate > $max_hourly_rate){
            $max_hourly_rate = $hourly_rate;
        }
    }               
} 

?>
```

And once you found the `max_hourly_rate` you can calculate the div width percentage as `($hourly_rate/$max_hourly_rate) * 100`

```
<div class="uk-progress">
    <div class="uk-progress-bar" style="width:<?php echo esc_attr($hourly_rate/$max_hourly_rate) * 100; ?>%;"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: Updated answer to `echo` width

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped. Just a small note, you forgot to add `echo`,   `style="width:<?php echo`. ^_~

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my answer to `echo` width correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the highest value by storing it in a temporary variable:

```
$temp = 0;
foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
    $all_hourly_rate    = get_the_author_meta( 'hourly_rate', $user->ID );
    echo '<p>' . $all_hourly_rate . '</p>';
    $temp = $all_hourly_rate > $temp ? $all_hourly_rate : $temp;
}
```

Then to calculate the percentage:

```
<div class="uk-progress-bar" style="width:<?php echo esc_attr( ($author_hourly_rate * 100) / $temp ); ?>%;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you; your answer helped as well. :)